# Broken vanity-gen program on OSX

Tags: c, macos, openssl, makefile

I can't get [Vanitygen](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen) to compile.

Is there a way to install an older version of openssl and make (compile) the program with it?
Or can someone who has an older version of openssl simply compile it for me and give me a link for it?
Are there any other ways to get this program to compile for me on OSX?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the first two sentences of this question and you might be able to save this question (which is starting to gather "off topic" or "not appropriate" votes to close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please make me a precompiled vanity-gen program on OSX?

You should try here:

- http://www.rentacoder.com
- http://www.freelancer.com

---

> It would compile fine if only I had a slightly older version of openssl.

You can get any version you like: [OpenSSL source code, tarballs](http://www.openssl.org/source/).

---

> I can't compile because I have the latest version of openssl.

You should fetch an older version of OpenSSL.

---

> Is there a way to install an older version of openssl and make (compile) the program with it?

Yes, there is!

```
$ wget http://w.tar.gzssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8y 
$ tar -xzf openssl-0.9.8y.tar.gz 
$ cd openssl-0.9.8y
$ ./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ssl-0.9.8
$ make all
$ sudo make install
```

You *might* need to add `export CFLAGS="-fPIC"`, but I don't recall. Do it right before you execute `config`.

Then, add `/usr/local/ssl-0.9.8/include` as an include directory; and add `/usr/local/ssl-0.9.8/lib` as a library directory.

Here's what it looks like on my Debian machine:

```
$ ls /usr/local/ssl-0.9.8/lib/
engines      libcrypto.so        libssl.a   libssl.so.0.9.8
libcrypto.a  libcrypto.so.0.9.8  libssl.so  pkgconfig
```

---

> Are there any other ways to get this program to compile for me on OSX?

OS X is another can of worms (or can be another can of worms). Once you have a version of OpenSSL installed that suites your taste, come back with configuration problems for `vanity-gen`.

For Mac OS X, I believe you can perform the following:

```
$ export KERNEL_BITS=64
$ ./config ...
```

If you don't export `KERNEL_BITS`, I believe you get a 32-bit configuration by default.

Comment: Still having no luck. I compiled with openssl 0.9.7 but at the very end i got a bunch of `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: Also tried with 1.0.1c, but to no avail

Comment: Got it to work. I had to uninstall the newest openssl. After I compiled it, I just reinstalled it.